# python file call another python script background and access variables?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, web-services

I have this scenario

I have a python script **webservice.py** (using cherrypy) running when linux starts

I have another script that dose som files copy and few loops **copyfiles.py** and save some values in few variables (x,y,z)

how I can call (going to http://localhost/start) **copyfiles.py** from **webservice.py** in the background and capture values x,y and z?

so when I call the http://localhost/status it reads the values (x,y and z) from the **copyfiles.py** and return it to the web?

so far I came with this in **webservice.py**

```
import cherrypy

cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
    'server.socket_port': 80,
})


class WebGUI(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "<!DOCTYPE html><html><title>Test 001</title><body><h1>Welcome to Test 001</h1></body></html>"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def start(self):
        subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", "copyfiles.py"])
        return "Files copy started ..."

    @cherrypy.expose
    def status(self):
        ..............
        ..............



if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(WebGUI())
```

Comment: `import copyfiles` and use thread to run in background function from `copyfiles` module.

Comment: I do not have functions, just the whole script do the job!

Comment: maybe create functions - you will have better control on code than running script in `subprocess`.

Comment: sounds good ... what about reading variables?